# Pass parameter from C# to Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, reporting-services, crystal-reports

I'm having trouble passing a parameter from a C# form to my report.
I have 3 stored procedures in sql server database MoM, which require @MoM_ID.
At first, when i was setting up my report I added these procedures into it and gave them the value 339 (@MoM_ID = 339). The only two options were to add the value or set it to NULL in order to continue.

After setting up my report, i added the following code to my C# form, that occurs on a button click. The code should pass the parameter to the stored procedures, and output the report as a pdf file, with the new values in the report. However when i do that, i always end up getting the same default values in the report where @MoM_ID was equal to 339.

This is the code:

```
ReportDocument reportDocument = new ReportDocument();
ParameterField paramField = new ParameterField();
ParameterFields paramFields = new ParameterFields();
ParameterDiscreteValue paramDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();

//Set instances for input parameter 1 -  @Dept
paramField.Name = "@MoM_ID(Action_Items)";
            //*Remember to reconstruct the paramDiscreteValue and paramField objects
paramDiscreteValue.Value = "337";
paramField.CurrentValues.Add(paramDiscreteValue);
//Add the paramField to paramFields
paramFields.Add(paramField);
crystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo = paramFields;

reportDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\nbousaba\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication4\WindowsFormsApplication4\Report1.rpt");
//Load the report by setting the report source
crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportDocument;
crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();

//set the database loggon information. 
reportDocument.SetDatabaseLogon("//USERNAME", "//PW", "//IP", "MoM");

//Creating a PDF file from the Crystal Report
try
{
    ExportOptions CrExportOptions ;
    DiskFileDestinationOptions CrDiskFileDestinationOptions = new DiskFileDestinationOptions();
    PdfRtfWordFormatOptions CrFormatTypeOptions = new PdfRtfWordFormatOptions();
    CrDiskFileDestinationOptions.DiskFileName = "c:\\testing123.pdf";
    CrExportOptions = reportDocument.ExportOptions;
    {
        CrExportOptions.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile;
        CrExportOptions.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat;
        CrExportOptions.DestinationOptions = CrDiskFileDestinationOptions;
        CrExportOptions.FormatOptions = CrFormatTypeOptions;
    }
    reportDocument.Export();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved with the following code, don't forget to link the subreports to the main report for the parameter to update.

```
    ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();

    TableLogOnInfos crtableLogoninfos = new TableLogOnInfos();
    TableLogOnInfo crtableLogoninfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
    ConnectionInfo crConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
    Tables CrTables;

    string path = "C:/Users/nbousaba/Documents/Visual Studio 2013/Projects/WindowsFormsApplication4/WindowsFormsApplication4/Report1.rpt";
    cryRpt.Load(path);

    cryRpt.SetParameterValue("@MoM_ID", x);

    crConnectionInfo.ServerName = ".";
    crConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "MoM";
    crConnectionInfo.UserID = "sa";
    crConnectionInfo.Password = "123456";

    CrTables = cryRpt.Database.Tables;
    foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table CrTable in CrTables)
    {
        crtableLogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo;
        crtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo;
        CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo);
    }

    crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;
    crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();


    //Creating a PDF file from Crystal Report
    try
    {
        ExportOptions CrExportOptions;
        DiskFileDestinationOptions CrDiskFileDestinationOptions = new DiskFileDestinationOptions();
        PdfRtfWordFormatOptions CrFormatTypeOptions = new PdfRtfWordFormatOptions();
        CrDiskFileDestinationOptions.DiskFileName = "c:\\MoM_Form"+x+".pdf";
        CrExportOptions = cryRpt.ExportOptions;
        {
            CrExportOptions.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile;
            CrExportOptions.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat;
            CrExportOptions.DestinationOptions = CrDiskFileDestinationOptions;
            CrExportOptions.FormatOptions = CrFormatTypeOptions;
        }

        cryRpt.Export();
```